# Що таке "велій"?

Tags: значення-слів

У Шевченка є такий вірш:

> Умре муж велій в власяниці.
>   Не плачте, сироти, вдовиці,
>   А ти, Аскоченський, восплач
>   Воутріє на тяжкий глас.
>   І Хомяков, Русі ревнитель,
>   Москви, отечества любитель,
>   О юбкоборцеві восплач.
>   І вся, о Русская беседа,
>   Во глас єдиний ісповєдуй
>   Свої гріхи.
>   І плач! і плач!

Вірш є сатиричним відгуком на смерть митрополита петербурзького і новгородського Григорія (Постникова Георгія Петровича), відомого своїми випадами проти освіти, науки і преси.
Не зрозуміле слово *велій*. В [російських](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/4835/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9) словниках знайшла варіант *великий*. За змістом, здається підходить - "*муж великий*", але інших підтверджень цьому не знайшла. То ж чи справді в даному випадку велій - це великий?

Answer (score 1):

Вірш Шевченка рясніє старослов'янізмами і русизмами, що надає особливого пафосу. Щодо значення слова велій є стаття на російськомовному [ресурсі](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-1726.htm):

> **ВЕЛИЙ** "большой", устар.; др.-русск., ст.-слав. велии, велиѭ (Супр.),
>   болг., макед. ве́лий, сербохорв. ве̑љи̑, др.-чеш. velí, чеш. vele
>   "очень", слвц. velo, в.-луж. wjele. Связано с вели́кий.